# Query is not running properly in Spark Submit but works fine in Hive

Tags: apache-spark, hive

Query running fine in Hive but while running the same Hive query from Spark Submit Command, it's not able to populate all of the columns giving null data instead of actual records.

Not able to load data in few columns

insert into tab2 select co1,col2,col3 from tab1.

Result:

Select * from tab2;

Null,Null,Actual_record